# Why my local storage is only appearing after a page reload?

Tags: reactjs, axios

This my Profile.js component and the code is:

```
  componentDidMount(){


        this.props.getPerson(1, this.props.history);

    }
```

The getPerson function does a get request to an API end-point to get user information about a person with the id 1. The function stores key information of that user in localStorages. When I want to print those local storages values in my Profile.js component, it only appears when the page reloads.

```
 <p>Hello {localStorage.getItem("abn")}</p>
 <p>Hello {localStorage.getItem("urole")}</p>
 <p>Hello {localStorage.getItem("address_business")}</p>
 <p>Hello {localStorage.getItem("phone_number")}</p>
```

What could be a possible solution for this?

Comment: Please provide enough information to reproduce your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking data from local storage within `render` will not re-render component. It gets it once, and does not track if it changes within storage.

My suggestion is, you should copy that local storage data into component state, then use it in `render`.